# error MSB8007 while downloading dependencies with npm and node

Tags: node.js, msbuild, npm

I am trying to install some packages in my node app with npm, and I keep getting the error below.  I get the same error with socket.io and mongo.  I have gone through a number of different errors similar to this, and have install so many different things as per suggestion in other threads that I really have no idea what the problem is.  If anyone has any suggestion as to what I need to download/set I would greatly appreciate it.

```
$ npm install mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.1.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos

> kerberos@0.0.2 install c:\Users\Ludicritz\Desktop\Umass-running-app\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


c:\Users\Ludicritz\Desktop\Umass-running-app\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos>node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bi
n\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

> bson@0.1.9 install c:\Users\Ludicritz\Desktop\Umass-running-app\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


c:\Users\Ludicritz\Desktop\Umass-running-app\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson>node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\.
.\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'kerberos.vcxp
roj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specifie
d a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [c:\Users\Ludicritz\Desktop\Umass-running-app\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerbero
s\build\kerberos.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'bson.vcxproj'
 is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a
non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [c:\Users\Ludicritz\Desktop\Umass-running-app\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\
bson.vcxproj]
mongodb@1.3.9 node_modules\mongodb
├── kerberos@0.0.2
└── bson@0.1.9
```

Comment: Install Windows 7 SDK and then VS C++ Express 2010 (whichever versions are appropriate for your OS)

Comment: I have installed both, same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VS C++ Express 2010 32bit is free. if you installed 64bit edition  of nodejs just remove it and install 32 bit version of the node.js

Comment: thank, solved my problem too~! Another confirmation to the answer's correctness

Comment: note that at this point in time, the 2010 version is starting to run into incompatibilities. However, thankfully the 2012 version is also free and works a treat.

Comment: Thanks, uninstalled node 64 bit and installed 32 bit and it worked. Would be useful if the official docs mentioned this!

Answer (score 3):

I had a simallar problem, and this is my solution. I am running windows 7 x64. I installed the x64 version of nodejs. I tried to run install and this is what I got:

At first it wanted me to put git into my path, which I did. then it wanted me to install python (not version 3.x.x but 2.x.x) and put that in my path, which I did. Then I installed visual studio 2010 (c++). after I did all of this I got this error:

*D:\Source\xxxx\grunt-raptr\node_modules\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.vcxproj(18,3):    error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

I read somewhere that if you run it in the visual studio cmd you can make it work, I tried that and I got this error:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'libxml.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [D:\Source\xxxx\node_modules\grunt-raptr\node_modules\libxmljs\build\vendor\libxml\libxml.
vcxproj]*

Once I saw this I re-installed nodejs with the x32 version and everything worked.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to install node-inspector: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'bufferutil.vcxproj' is invalid.  Platform='x64'`

My machine:

- Win 7 64bit
- node 0.12.7 64bit
- Python 2.7 64bit

How I fixed it with all the advice found on the nets:

- Uninstall all VC++ 20xx Redistributables

  - (use this [MS FixIt](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/mats/program_install_and_uninstall) if the uninstall fails)
- Install [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

  - Select only `Visual C++ Compilers`
- Run `npm install -g node-inspector --python="C:\Python27\python.exe"`

If that still doesn't work try this:

- install the MS SDK `x64 Libraries`
- add this line `'AdditionalLibraryDirectories': 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1\\Lib\\x64',` in every `addon.gypi` you find

  - `C:\nodejs\node_modules\node-gyp\addon.gypi`
  - `C:\Users\YOU\.node-gyp\0.12.7\deps\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\addon.gypi`
  - ?

`addon.gypi`:

`...
'msvs_settings': {
  'VCLinkerTool': {
    'DelayLoadDLLs': [ 'iojs.exe', 'node.exe' ],
    # Don't print a linker warning when no imports from either .exe
    # are used.
    'AdditionalOptions': [ '/ignore:4199' ],
    # THIS LINE HERE
    'AdditionalLibraryDirectories': 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1\\Lib\\x64',
},
...`

Good luck!